# How to replace function that call MySQL with query to function that take query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this function that make query to MySQL:

```
    const getAllUserReports = (userID) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(
          `SELECT reports.id,report_types.name,companies.id as companyID,reports.year,reports.deadLine
          FROM reports
          INNER JOIN report_types ON reports.typeID=report_types.id
          INNER JOIN companies ON reports.companyID=companies.id
          WHERE reports.creatorUserID=${userID} and reports.active      
          `,
          (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
          }
        );
      });
};
```

and more function like this. I want to change it to function that get the query from external file and just make the call. Example:

```
// Get report by ID
const getReportByID = (query,reportID) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(query(reportID),
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(result);
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Don't add variables to a query without proper escaping, (`reports.creatorUserID=${userID}`) and use insertion points instead, so that the mysql module does the proper escaping for you. This would also be one step to a solution of your problem.

Comment: I dont understand your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const getQuery = async (reportID) => {
    const query = await readFromFileOrOtherPlace(reportID);
    return doSomeValidatingParsingEtc(query);
};

const getReportByID = (reportID) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let query = await getQuery(reportID);
        connection.query(query,
            (err, result) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(result);
            }
        );
    });
};
```